# Redirect to external URL

Tags: node.js, redirect, angularjs

I am using AngularJs with NodeJs.

I have a scenario when upon a successful HTTP POST request, I need to redirect the user.

In the client through AngularJS, I make a HTTP POST request to a route:

```
$http.post('/aPath', data)
    .success(function (result) {
        //Handle success
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        //Handle error
    });
```

This route is handled within NodeJs that then does the actual POST. Upon success, within the route handler, I redirect:

```
function handlePostRequest (req, res) {
    //Route handler
    //HTTP POST Request

    //Following code called when POST request is successful
    if (result) {
        //Successful post
        res.redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

However, the browser does not navigate to google. Instead, in the error handler of the POST request within the AngularJS client, the control is reached.

I checked the server and find that the POST request is returned as status code 302 and thus is picked by the error handler for the POST request in the client.

I cannot figure out why, when the server successfully executes the redirect code, the control still reaches the client and that too the error handler. How do I redirect successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a HTTP POST in angular or an XHR?  If it's an XHR you can't redirect the client from serverside, you'd need to send back an error which you then handle in your clientside script such as:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url:    'yoururl',
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // success stuff
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (status == 302) {
       window.location = headers('Location');
    }
})
```

Comment: Its an HTTP Post. I have edited my code to reflect the same. I am expecting that the server redirects... If not, I will take the "check http response status in error handler" approach - with this approach, is it possible to know which URL to redirect to? I do not want to hard code the redirect url and would like to read from the server's response, if possible?

Comment: Ahh... I see your edited answer now... So, `headers('Location')` will redirect to the location that the server was attempting to redirect, correct?

Comment: Yeah since res.redirect('blah') in node is going to stick that header in the response - so should be readable with headers('Location') as OZ_ edited.

Comment: Yes, this will work, but 302 is not an error and really shouldn't be treated as such. If the POST is successful a 200 is really what should be returned and then the route change should happen in the .success block. You shouldn't need to add a header to get your redirect location. Your POST can return that value and you can pick it up in the data variable.

Comment: status parameter returns as 0. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Successful XHRs come back with a status of 200. Your server handing back a 302 is technically correct, but it isn't what $http in Angular is expecting. If your server can hand you a 200, you can then do your redirect in the .success function of the $http request.